# Generate input type="tel" with JSF

Tags: jsf

In order to make the site mobile friendly, I want to add

```
<input type="email">
```

and

```
<input type="tel">
```

But I have to use JSF like

```
<h:inputText  value="#{connetcionController.userName}" />
```

How can we generate html input type with JSF ?

I am also using primefaces and do they have a similar feature?

Comment: There is no way out of the box, but you can use some kind of JavaScript validator / formatter.

Comment: Is HTML5 mobile friendly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using PrimeFaces, you should be able to use `type` with `<p:inputText>` in this way

```
<p:inputText type="email" ... />
```

or

```
<p:inputText type="tel" ... />
```

If you want to keep using `<h:inputText>`, you need to upgrade to a minimum of JSF 2.2 and add the new XML namespace `xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"`, then you should be able to override `type` of `<h:inputText>` in this way

```
<h:inputText a:type="email" ... />
```

or

```
<h:inputText a:type="tel" ... />
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a very easy way. You can use pass-through.
Add this to your html tag

```
xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

You can then add your input type.
You have to add an `a:` before.

```
<h:inputText a:type="email" value="#{profileBean.student.privateMail}"/>
```

This also works with some other definitions, like placeholder

```
<h:inputSecret a:placeholder="Password" value="#{loginBean.credentials.password}" />
```

Comment: Note: requires a minimum of JSF 2.2. Wasn't available in older versions (thus also not at the moment this question was asked).

Answer (score 1):

[OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) provides a solution. See [this explanation](http://balusc.blogspot.co.nz/2012/06/adding-html5-attributes-to-standard-jsf.html) on how to use omnifaces for your situation.

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp it is only working on some browsers... hope they will be implemented everywhere soon!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jQuery plugin to mask a normal `<input id="phone" />` like that :

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

Using this plugin : http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces Extensions comes with `pe:inputPhone` which renders the input with `type="tel"`. Besides that it offers validation, formatting and more options.

See:

- https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/inputphone/basicUsage.jsf